# Location and data of wind turbines

Tags: data-request, geospatial, energy

Where can I find a geo-database of wind turbines for electricity/power production, including their location, capacity (max power), construction year, and other details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## *Community Wiki*

---

### United States

the **[USWTDB](https://eerscmap.usgs.gov/uswtdb/)** (US Wind Turbine DataBase), *as seen on [hackernews](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=20322276)*

> The USWTDB combines a 2014 USGS data set (48,956 wind turbines, including decommissioned and duplicate turbines) with a 2017 LBNL data set (43,827 wind turbines) and includes regular updates from AWEA’s WindIQ as well as the Federal Aviation Administration (FAA) Digital Obstacle File (DOF) and Obstacle Evaluation Airport Airspace Analysis (OE-AAA). The USWTDB is updated as frequently as quarterly as new data become available and will lag installations by approximately one quarter.

- **[Raw data](https://eerscmap.usgs.gov/uswtdb/data/)** (links for shapefile/geojson, CSV, geo-web-services)
- **[Viewer](https://eerscmap.usgs.gov/uswtdb/viewer/#3/37.25/-96.25)**:

[image]

If you zoom in, individual turbines have a tooltip:

[image]

*License:*

> Map services and data downloaded from the U.S. Wind Turbine Database are free and in the public domain. There are no restrictions; however, we request that the following acknowledgment statement be included in products and data derived from our map services when citing, copying, or reprinting

---

---

### Switzerland

https://opendata.swiss/en/dataset/windenergieanlagen2

> The “Wind energy plants” geodata document the current situation regarding wind energy facilities in Switzerland. All data are based on information provided by the power plant operators and are intended to function as information material for the general public.

- [Data download](https://data.geo.admin.ch/ch.bfe.windenergieanlagen/)
- [WMS](http://wms.geo.admin.ch/?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetCapabilities&lang=de)

Answer (score 2):

There is a website, Aneroid Energy (https://anero.id/energy/fossil-energy), visualising all kinds of power plants in Australia and their corresponding hourly dispatches.

For example, their precise locations, capacities and current states:

[image]

and detailed time series regarding power generations:

[image]

More data is provided by Australian Energy Market Operator (AEMO) (https://aemo.com.au/).

---

Federal Network Agency (Bundesnetzagentur) provides a list describing available pow­er plant in Germany. I am not sure if it contains geographical information.

- https://www.bundesnetzagentur.de/EN/Areas/Energy/Companies/SecurityOfSupply/GeneratingCapacity/PowerPlantList/PubliPowerPlantList_node.html