# Wind power generation in Germany (location, actual operation of turbines)

Tags: data-request, energy, germany

I'm looking for microdata on the **location** and **actual operation** of wind turbines in Germany. There is a similar question ([see here](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/15461/location-and-data-of-wind-turbines)), however it is from 2019 and links (e.g. to German plant listings) are broken.

I don't need actual energy generation. However, I would need information on if some wind turbine was actually operating at some point in time or not plus the respective location of the turbine.

Alternatively, the location and the date a wind turbine (or wind park) assumed operation would be an option for me as well.

I know that [Bundesnetzagentur](https://www.bundesnetzagentur.de/EN/Home/home_node.html) published data on wind turbines in the past, but I don't know what is published exactly (and where).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be a bit late but I was looking for the same kind of data recently. You can find the data on German power plants on this [platform](https://www.marktstammdatenregister.de/MaStR).

This is the official registry in Germany since 2019. They provide information on the location, the capacity and the status. I hope it will help you.

Comment: Nice, they even provide a download (XML) of the whole dataset https://www.marktstammdatenregister.de/MaStR/Datendownload